# Why is there a "sync" of the entry file's directory in webpack as the last build/bundle step?

Tags: webpack

When I run webpack with an a singular entry file, webpack does a sync step even with a minimal webpack config setup. Anyone know why it's doing this and how to stop it?

Entry point: entry: './_tmp/browser/main/App.js'

Last build/bundle step always syncs the entry file's folder with files ending in .js but I have no module or loader that's instructing it to do that.

[4] ./_tmp/browser/main sync ^./.*.js$

```
const webConfig = {
target: 'web',
entry: './_tmp/browser/main/App.js',
output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist/browser',
    filename: 'bundle.file.js',
    library: 'run',
    libraryTarget: 'var'
},
externals: {
    ramda: 'R',
    jquery: '$'
},
optimization: {
    minimize: false,
},
plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin({
        patterns: [
            {
                from: '_tmp/browser/tmp/main.css',
                to: 'backstage.css'
            }
        ],
    }),
],
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
                'style-loader',
                {
                    loader: 'css-loader',
                    options: {
                        modules: true
                    }
                }
            ],
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'url-loader',
                    options: {
                        mimetype: 'image/png',
                        limit: 8192
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
},
```

}

module.exports = [webConfig];

Comment: could you provide more details on your webpack config ?

Comment: @Danish I've updated it with the webpack config

Comment: It can be due to style-loader, as it has to modify the js importing css files via loader..